# Hiding input borders in print stylesheet (chrome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, media-queries

I have a form that, when printed, should display as plain text, i.e. the inputs and textareas should have no borders.
I've added a print stylesheet, something like

```
@media print {
    input, textarea {
        border: 0 !important;
        border-style: none !important;
    }
}
```

This works in FF, but not in chrome.

```
-webkit-shadow and
-webkit-appearance
```

also don't appear to affect the print output.

See: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rych/s1aoaydy/1/)

**Edit**: This is ultimately caused by:

> Chrome Issue [174583](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174583): box-shadow, when printed, appears solid black .

A suggested workaround of adding *-webkit-filter:blur(0)* kinda works, but still leaves traces of the input border shadow, so a javascript workaround like that in the accepted answer seems the best approach for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's caused by the bootstrap class `.form-control` and its `box-shadow` property. It seems difficult to remove with CSS (seems like a Chrome print bug to me). How about removing the class on print with jQuery? The default input styles can be removed with the @media query as normal.

### Working Example

You would probably want to target the normal browser print event as well.

```js
$( ".print-now" ).on( "click", function() { //the print button has the class .print-now
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent normal button action 
   $('.form-control').removeClass('form-control'); // remove the form-control class
    window.print(); // print the page
    $('input').addClass('form-control'); // return the class after printing
});
```

```css
@media print {
  button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  input,
  textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input input-small" maxlength="3" value="some" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-medium" value="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="form-control btn btn-warning print-now">Print me!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<p>When the above is printed, there should be NO borders on the inputs.</p>
<p>How to accomplish this?</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  I've found the Chrome bug : Issue [174583](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174583): box-shadow, when printed, appears solid black.

Comment: Instead of adding class form-control to all input, I prefer to add them to previous list only by following code:
                $objList = $('.form-control').removeClass('form-control'); 
                window.print(); 
                $objList.addClass('form-control');

Comment: Just a note: you could attach the script to the beforePrint and afterPrint events so you can get all working even if the user launch the print  through the browser button or menu item.

Answer (score 6):

Just add `transition: none` to `.form-control` :D

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
@media print {
  .form-control, .form-control.nobug {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .form-control.nobug {
    transition: none; /*-- THIS IS IMPORTANT -- */
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.print()">Print with your Chrome</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="form-control bug">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control nobug" value="no bug (disable transition)">
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: transition: none; FTW.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use "outline" instead of "border" *(or in addition to border)*

```
@media print {
    input, textarea {
        outline: none !important;
    } 
}
```

also, try `border: none` instead of `border: 0` as well, may help if still having issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but all permutations I've tried of outline and border, 0, none, '0 none', etc have not worked.

Comment: Yes, they do.  When used in the screen-targeted css, box-shadow: none !important; does the trick, and it prints without borders.  Within the print media block, it seems to be ignored.